# How can i use sed to replace a line of text containing a dollar sign?

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying to use sed to replace a line of text in a configuration file.

Original text:

```
%prod.db=${DATABASE_URL}?ssl=true&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory"
```

Desired text:

```
%prod.db=${DATABASE_URL}?ssl=true&sslmode=require&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory"
```

I tried the following:

```
old="%prod.db=\${DATABASE_URL}?ssl=true&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory"
new="%prod.db=\${DATABASE_URL}?ssl=true&sslmode=require&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory"
sed  's/^'"$old"'.*/'"$new"'/g' filename
```

And somehow ended up with this result:

```
%prod.db=${DATABASE_URL}?ssl=true%prod.db=${DATABASE_URL}?ssl=true&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactorysslmode=require%prod.db=${DATABASE_URL}?ssl=true&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactorysslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory
```

I assume the dollar sign is causing the issue and that it needs to be escaped somehow, but i have tried multiple ways to escape the replacement text without success, for example this answer: [Escape a string for a sed replace pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/407523/escape-a-string-for-a-sed-replace-pattern)

I would be really grateful if anyone could help me solve this issue.

Comment: The `&`s must be escaped  in the `new`.

Answer (score 0):

Reason on using ampersand operator using stream editor(sed/vim/vi):

```
$ echo murugesan openssl | sed "s/./& /g;"
m u r u g e s a n   o p e n s s l
```

Here & refer to the search string/any given pattern.
Since I searched . (any character)
All characters(using /g where g referring global) all being replaced with
same character followed by a space character.
Sample output:

```
$ echo stackoverflow | sed "s/...../& /;s/ ..../ & /;"
stack  over flow
```

vi delete.txt
Press i
type any text and few lines.
Press Esc and type the following:
:%s/./& /g
After typing g press Enter
Same replaced will happen inside current editor (vim.exe/vi/vim) based on your OS.